# SUM up downlines points to create a Group total - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

refer to the image:

[image]

I have a list of members each with an ID as well as a Seq# and a Max Seq number of their furthest downline in terms of a hierarchy. Each member has personal points. I need to be able to generate total downline points based on personal points.

Essentially saying, sum up all personal points for anyone between that particular member's seq# and max Downline Seq and call it "group points" on another column.

In the image, member ID 1206740 (third from last) would have 280.26 personal points, as well as the personal points of ID 372549 (second to last) and 33675 (last) because their individual seq# falls between that of ID 1206740 Seq# and max downline Seq#. So a total of  1477.39 downline points, and 1757.65 total group points.

I have the below which doesn't really work as it gives the same points for personal and group

```
SELECT 

    ID, 
    PERSONAL_POINTS,
    SUM (CASE 
            WHEN SEQ_NO BETWEEN SEQ_NO AND MAX_DWNLN_SEQ_NO
            THEN PERSONAL_POINTS 
            ELSE 0 
        END) GROUP_POINTS


FROM 
    points

GROUP BY 
    ID, 
    PERSONAL_POINTS
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Maybe take PERSONAL_POINTS out of the query AND the group by?

Comment: You're summing from a CASE where you're taking PERSONAL_POINTS or 0, this requires some clarification as to what you're trying to do.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the data in a form that can be readily copied or turned into row consructors

Comment: As it is now, a `case when x between x and y then x else 0 end` will always return x.

Answer (score 0):

As LukStorms pointed out your case statement will always return Personal_Points.

I think what you want to do is have that table join on itself.

Maybe try:

```
select 
  P1.ID,
  P1.Personal_Points,
  sum(P2.Personal_Points) Group_Points
from Points P1
inner join Points P2 on P1.Seq_No between P2.Seq_No and P2.Max_Dwnln_Seq_no
group by 
  P1.ID, P1.Personal_Points
```

Edit: proof of concept

```
create table #temp (id int, seq_no int, max_seq_no int, points decimal (10,2))
insert into #temp (id, seq_no, max_seq_no, points) values(1841287,97,112,0)
insert into #temp (id, seq_no, max_seq_no, points) values(1841289,120,131,233.48)
insert into #temp (id, seq_no, max_seq_no, points) values(18409596,388,599980,76822.22)
insert into #temp (id, seq_no, max_seq_no, points) values(61,599981,727456,2.4)
insert into #temp (id, seq_no, max_seq_no, points) values(1206740,602811,606419,280.26)
insert into #temp (id, seq_no, max_seq_no, points) values(372549,602813,602959,37.04)
insert into #temp (id, seq_no, max_seq_no, points) values(33675,603002,605076,1440.35)



select 
  P1.ID,
  P1.Points,
  sum(P2.Points) Group_Points
from #temp P1
inner join #temp P2 on P1.Seq_No between P2.Seq_No and P2.max_seq_no
group by 
  P1.ID, P1.Points


drop table #temp
```

Comment: The above worked! With a minor fix.

The inner join should be p2.Seq_No between P1.Seq_No and P2.max_seq_no

Comment: Correction: The inner join should be p2.Seq_No between P1.Seq_No and P1.max_seq_no